# dojo.io.iframe.send does not send a request on second time onwards in dojo 1.8

Tags: dojo

Example code snippet

```
this._deferred = dojo.io.iframe.send({
        url: "/Some/Servie",
        method: "post",
        handleAs: 'html',
        content: {},
        load: function(response, ioArgs){
            //DO successfull callback
        },
        error: function(response, ioArgs){  
            // DO Failer callback
        }
    });
```

Steps

1. click submit button send a request and successfully got a response
2. click submit button again...request never send...

Appreciate any help

Comment: From the sound of it, there are some issues with dojo.io.iframe in 1.7 and 1.8: http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15740

Comment: Is this issue has been resolved,i have tried all the below suggestion but still my issue exists. Am using dojo1.7.

Answer (score 2):

I can't talk for 1.8, but I am using dojo 1.6 and had a very similar issue that I resolved with the following method:

```
dojo.io.iframe._currentDfd = null; //insert this line
dojo.io.iframe.send
({...
```

*verified in Chrome Version 25.0.1364.152 m

Source: http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2012-May/066109.html

Answer (score 2):

`dojo.io.frame.send` will only send one request at a time, so if it thinks that the first request is still processing (whether it actually is or not), it won't work on the second call.  The trick is to call `cancel()` on the returned deferred result if one exists, like so:

```
if (this._deferred) {
    this._deferred.cancel();
}
this._deferred = dojo.io.iframe.send({
....
```

that will cancel the first request and allow the second request to send properly.

Answer (score 0):

For dojo 1.8, `dojo.io.iframe` is deprecated. `dojo.request.iframe` is used instead.

And the solution from @Sorry-Im-a-N00b still works:

```
iframe._currentDfd = null;

iframe.get(url, {
    data: sendData,
});
```